# Restrict Google custom search by date range but keep default sorting?

Tags: google-custom-search, google-apis-explorer

I want to run a google custom search and apply a date range restriction. I can do this using the "sort" attribute with something like "sort=date:r:20160101:20170101" but this seems to not only restrict the data by date, but it also applies a sort by date (which I don't want).

The docs state that you can apply multiple sorting attributes (comma separated) so I'd like to sort by the default sorting option first then apply the date range filter as a second "sort". I'm hoping this will achieve what I want.

Does anyone know what the default sorting option is or how I can apply a date range filter without affecting the result set's ordering?

I've been looking at these docs:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#sort_by_attribute
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#restrict_to_range

Answer (score 0):

It akways defaults to relevance. go to setup, search features, advanved,  and check off sort by date